# How to know if bash has readline library support?

Tags: bash, shell, command-line, shared-library

This question is related to https://askubuntu.com/q/826288/295286 In my search online, I could find no mention of whether bash 3.2 comes with readline support. Thus, I would like to know, if there is a systematic way of finding out what libraries bash uses.

In the linked question , I used `locate` to search for `readline.so` ,but that approach seems a bit unreliable to me.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is probably a duplicate (I recall it being answered).  But:

- bash [**bundles**](http://www.businessdictionary.com/definition/bundle.html) readline, and
- will use the bundled version of readline unless
- it is specially configured, and
- the bundled version is statically linked, so
- you are unlikely to see it as a shared library dependency of bash.

For example:

```
$ ldd /bin/bash
        linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffeae9a5000)
        libncurses.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so.5 (0x00007fe9bc832000)
        libtinfo.so.5 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtinfo.so.5 (0x00007fe9bc608000)
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007fe9bc403000)
        libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007fe9bc062000)
        /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x000055a30b725000)
```

On the other hand, the dependency in Debian/testing upon `libncurses.so.5` is unnecessary (bash uses **only** the termcap interface which is provided by `libtinfo.so.5`).

If you want to see that bash uses readline, use `nm -D` (Linux...) to see the symbol table:

```
$ nm -D /bin/bash |grep readline
00000000006ffab0 B bash_readline_initialized
00000000006fce00 B current_readline_line
00000000006fcdf8 B current_readline_line_index
00000000006fce08 B current_readline_prompt
000000000046d600 T initialize_readline
0000000000475400 T pcomp_set_readline_variables
000000000046d360 T posix_readline_initialize
000000000049a450 T readline
0000000000499d30 T readline_internal_char
0000000000499300 T readline_internal_setup
0000000000499430 T readline_internal_teardown
00000000006f7910 D rl_gnu_readline_p
00000000006fca20 D rl_readline_name
00000000007003f8 B rl_readline_state
00000000006f7914 D rl_readline_version
```

The external symbols (essentially the same approach) show these entrypoints for the **termcap** interface:

```
             U tgetent 
             U tgetflag
             U tgetnum 
             U tgetstr
             U tgoto  
             U tputs
```

(some people become confused by the libncurses dependency and suppose that bash uses ncurses — [termcap applications](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses.faq.html#uses_of_library) are a special case).